# Avoiding ValueError repetitively

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider this code :

```
def meh():
  try:
    n=int(input("\nEnter any number : "))
  except ValueError:
    n=int(input("\nERROR!! Kindly enter a number only! : "))
```

I am trying to avoid an output like this :

```
Enter any number : a
ERROR!! Kindly enter a number only! : a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in meh
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in meh
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

Basically, my goal is to achieve only an integer irrespective of how many times I input string value.
I will be very thankful if you guys let me know of a way to do so!

Comment: Just use an infinite loop and braek if there is no error.

Comment: Writing a simple condition will help (or) just use an infinite loop and break as @t.m.adam said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
def meh():
  try:
    n=int(input("\nEnter any number : "))
  except ValueError:
    print('ERROR!! Kindly enter a number only!')
    meh()
```

Previously, when the function got the non-integer type string second time, it would throw the same `ValueError` again as there is no other `try` block in `except` part. So, just call the function again in the `except` block with an dummy error printing before.

**OUTPUT** :

```
>>> meh()

Enter any number : d
ERROR!! Kindly enter a number only!

Enter any number :
ERROR!! Kindly enter a number only!

Enter any number : a
ERROR!! Kindly enter a number only!

Enter any number : g
ERROR!! Kindly enter a number only!

Enter any number : dsfdsg
ERROR!! Kindly enter a number only!

Enter any number : 4243
```

Comment: Suppose I didn't define meh() and everything in the code was declared globally, then how would you tackle the problem?
Thanks btw!! I am just curious about scenarios where using user-defined functions will be a hassle.

Answer (score 1):

I agree to other answers but enclosing your code in try/except is not a good idea.

```
def meh():
    n = input("Enter any number:")
    if not n.isdigit():
        raise ValueError('ERROR!! Kindly enter a number only!')
    return int(n)
```

Then you can call it like

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        try:
            j=meh()
            print ('You entered ', j)
            break
        except ValueError as e:
            print (e)
            continue
```

You will get the output like:

```
[test@localhost google_fin]$ python ~/test.py
Enter any number:k
ERROR!! Kindly enter a number only!
Enter any number:k
ERROR!! Kindly enter a number only!
Enter any number:k
ERROR!! Kindly enter a number only!
Enter any number:k
ERROR!! Kindly enter a number only!
Enter any number:2
You entered  2
```

Comment: "enclosing your code in try/except is not a good idea." Well that's just plain untrue.